# LOW Memory...Java Heap Maxed Out (Ax)

Tags: java, heap-memory

How to avoid this error... Please help me out.

```
Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x007eb378 nid=0xfec runnable [0x00000000..0x00000000] 

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x007e9f38 nid=0xf14 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0x0e55f850] 

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x007e92b8 nid=0xe70 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0x00000000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Increase the size of your heap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1109778) if you can. Do this after first verifying that there is not something more fundamentally wrong with your memory usage.

Comment: +1 Similarly, try increasing the amount of memory you have. Even 16 GD of memory doesn't cost much these days. (This will increase the default maximum heap size)

Answer (score 0):

To increase maximum Java heap size to, say 512 megabytes, use -Xmx512m as a parameter to the Java executable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the size of maximum heap size and the size of intial heap size by -Xms -Xmx options.
For see complete option for this goals and other improvements go to : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html